# NullPointerException in DoSAttack2 example with CEP

Tags: fiware, complex-event-processing

I'm using CEP (cep-r5.4.3-img) for the DoSAttack2.json example and when I try to make a POST like this: 
http://public_IP:8080/ProtonOnWebServer/rest/events 
with Headers = Content-Type : application/json
Body = 
{ 
    "Name":"TrafficReport", 
     "volume":"1000" 
}

I've got this error:

```
INFO: started event message body reader
Jan 07, 2017 10:58:50 AM com.ibm.hrl.proton.webapp.providers.EventJSONMessageReader readFrom
INFO: name value: TrafficReport looking for: Name
Jan 07, 2017 10:58:50 AM com.ibm.hrl.proton.webapp.providers.EventJSONMessageReader readFrom
SEVERE: Could not parse json event java.lang.NullPointerException, reason: null
```

Could you help me?

Regards,

Pasquale

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Hi Filburt, my question is not duplicate ... it's regard on CEP.

Answer (score 1):

To address the exact issue I would need the Tomcat logs (catalina.out), specifically the part where the Proton application has initialization messages.

A condition like this usually arises when the application is not initialized properly - there is an error in the definition file for example and therefore the configuration is not loaded, or the paths to the configuration are not defined properly.

To diagnose exactly though I would require the log file.

Comment: My log is: Jan 19, 2017 8:43:33 AM com.ibm.hrl.proton.webapp.providers.EventJSONNgsiMessageRead‌​er readFrom SEVERE: Could not parse JSON NGSI event org.apache.wink.json4j.JSONException: The key [data] was not in the map, reason: The key [data] was not in the map